# Pull all entity attributes and values given a set of entity IDs in Datomic

Tags: datomic

I have a hashset of Entity IDs:

```
#{1234 5678 9012 4864 ...}
```

How can I return a collection of maps of each Entity's attributes and values. I am guessing this is done with the pull api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, for instance with `pull-many`:

```
(require '[datomic.api :as d])
(d/pull-many db '[*] (seq #{1234 5678 9012 4864}))
```

Comment: Are you sure it will work with a hashmap? I can get it to work with a vector by (vec #{1234 5678 ...}) but not using the hashmap directly?

Comment: Correct, it needs to implement java.util.List, so you can use `vec` or `seq` to convert it to one.